# Labeling the top 3 entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, labeling

my question is finding out how to label the top 3 entries based on column "avg_score, in a table, while still showing the rest of the entries, but without a label. So say I have a table like this:

```
 Entry   avg_score

entry_1 | 4.3
entry_2 | 9.4
entry_3 | 4.6
entry_4 | 7.1
entry_5 | 2.1
entry_6 | 1.9
```

I want to be able to find the top 3 based on the column 'avg_score' and display it like:

"1st place: entry_2

2nd place: entry_4

3rd place: entry_3

entry_1

entry_5

entry_6"

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you must make your query which would order by avg_score desceing.

After that you can do something like this:

```
<?
$x = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    if($x < 4){
        echo $x.". place: ";
    }
    echo $row['Entry'];
}
?>
```

if you want it to show 1st etc then use:

```
<?
$x = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    if($x == 1){echo "1st place: ";
    }elseif($x == 2){echo "2nd place: ";
    }elseif($x == 3){echo "3rd place: ";}
    echo $row['Entry']."<br />";
    $x++;
}
?>
```

Comment: this didnt work, it echoed: "1. entry_2 1.entry_4 1.entry_3 1. entry_1 etc."

Comment: Change one line to
echo $row['Entry']."<br />";
and after that add
$x++; in the next line

Comment: ok perfect! is there any way I can make the labeling system say "1st, 2nd, 3rd" instead of "1. 2. 3."

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do this is to define a rank and then use the rank to determine the strings to prepend to the entry name:

```
select concat(case when rank = 1 then '1st place: '
                   when rank = 2 then '2nd place: '
                   when rank = 3 then '3rd place: '
                   else ''
              end, entry)
from (select t.*, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
      from t cross join (select @rank := 0) const
      order by avg_score desc
     ) t
```

Comment: awesome, so how would I be able to put all of this into separate variables to be able to customize everything in php?

Comment: @MikeKochendorfer . . . If I understand the question correctly, just use the subquery.  It will have the rank.